# Not able to click on td clickable element in dynamic website using python Selenium

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use `click()` command in selenium webdriver using python. But when automated browser window opens, I see that column which contains clickable `td` elements is not there and therefore my script doesn't work. Can someone help me or guide me if there is other way around,

Here is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
url = 'https://www.londonstockexchange.com/live-markets/market-data-dashboard/price-explorer?categories=BONDS'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'price-explorer-results-wrapper')))

td_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.clickable.instrument-name.gtm-trackable.td-with-link')

for td in td_elements:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.clickable.instrument-name.gtm-trackable.td-with-link")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", td)
        td.click()
    except:
        print("Could not click element")
driver.quit()
```

Which just prints "Could not click element" in the console, as it is not there when on automated browser window opens.

URL link : https://www.londonstockexchange.com/live-markets/market-data-dashboard/price-explorer?categories=BONDS

What I want automated using python is that, when I click on company name like (3i group plc) which is a link under Name column it opens and then from this new link https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/957X/3i-group-plc/company-page. I get Instrument information data from the website. but here I am stuck at first phase of clicking names and moving to new browser.

below is the html part :

```
<table _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 id="price-explorer-results-wrapper" class="full-width-price-explorer-results">
  <thead _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170> ...</thead> == $0
  <tbody _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170>
      <tr _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 class="medium-font-weight slide-panel">
        <td _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 class="clickable bold-font-weight instrument-tidm code gtm-trackable td-with-link">...</td>
        <td _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 class="clickable instrument-name gtm-trackable td-with-link">
        <span _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 class="ellipsed">3i group plc</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 class="medium-font-weight slide-panel"></tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 class="medium-font-weight slide-panel"></tr>
      
    <div _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 class>
```

This part `<div _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 class>` changes to `<div _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c170 class="disabled">`, is this the reason if so how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

Once you execute your script you have to accept the cookies to access to the rest of the HTML.

This line accepts cookies:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]').click()
```

Once you clicked the cookies button try this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-handshake/div/app-page-content/app-price-explorer/section/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span').click()
```

The second window opens with this one:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/app-root/app-handshake/div/app-page-content/app-price-explorer/section/app-popup-table/section/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr[2]/td[2]/app-link-or-dash/a').click()
```

I put some `time.sleep(1)` between clicks / commands.